# Doing something different with last sequence in a loop

Tags: c#

I am looking for the basic syntax of doing something different with the last itteration through a loop, using C#

Comment: Check out this link you will get a complete knowledge about the loops http://www.dotnetperls.com/loop

Comment: If you want to do something entirely different, then maybe you should set your loop to do one iteration less, and then perform your last iteration's work _outside_ the loop.

Comment: I was curious as to what it looks like not working with anything inparticular

Answer (score 4):

There is no special syntax for it.

Here's just one possible way to do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (i == n - 1)
    {
        // Something special that must be done before the last iteration
    }

    // Normal iteration
}
```

Comment: I agree with the idea, although that syntax, as it stands, would make it better to just move the last iteration's logic outside the loop.

Comment: The edited version makes the intention clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Wha kind of loop, what kind of collection?

Assuming it's something with a `Count` property from `ICollection`:

```
for(int i=0; i < col.Count; i++)
{
    if(i == col.Count-1)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

for all other you could use [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method which executes queries and enumerates them to determine the count (if the type is castable to `ICollection<T>` it will use the `Count` property):

```
int index = 0;
int count = col.Count();
foreach(var x in col)
{
    if(index++ == count - 1)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add something about IEnumerable and IQueryable too to make it complete.

Comment: @Candide: Not sure if that it what you've meant. It would take us too far afield if i would start explaing linq and deferred execution.

Comment: HA! Not that far. Just wanted to see a reference to `Count()` which you did.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any sequence of `T`,

```
bool waitingForOne = true;
T last = default(T);
foreach (T t in MySequenceOfT) // or for over whole collection or while...
{
    if (!waitingForOne)
        doSomethingWith(last);
    else
        waitingForOne = false;
    last = t;        
}
if (!waitingForOne)
    doSomethingElseWith(last);
```

The idea is, on each iteration, you hold on to the *current* item and do something to the *previous* item, if there was one. At the end, you do something *else* to the *last* item.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var collection = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
        for (var i = collection.Length - 2; i > -1; i--)
        {
            // do something with
            var element = collection[i];
        }

        // now do something with
        var last = collection.Last();
```